# How to read the text file from the Application Directory text file

Tags: c#, text-files, windows, applicationdomain

I have a text file in the application project classpath Directory of Windows Form Application. Now at the time of installation I am trying to write a text value into the text file. Here is my Installer class code for text file..

```
File.WriteAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\" + "ConnectionString.txt",param3);
```

After installation I want to retrieve the text that is entered in the "ConnectionString.txt" file and use it in the application but I am not getting how to retrieve the text value present in the text file.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try the following code snippet

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "ConnectionString.txt")
```

**Read Text File**

```
string result = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "ConnectionString.txt"));
```

Comment: You can completely leave out the path here - it is relative to the calling assembly location anyway.

Comment: @geek Sir i am getting this error "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\vikas\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\TechSoft CallBill\TechSoft CallBill.exe\ConnectionString.txt'."